# How emulate real size dimensions in css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I need to display an object with its real size on a web app. If an object has 85mm width, so should it also be displayed on the screen (ipad 1,2,3 and androids). I tried to set the images in mm units in the css, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use `85mm`. `mm` is valid unit.

Comment: If you tried the `mm` unit but it doesn't match up with the scale in real life, than you will have to adjust your DPI value on the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @feeela mentioned, the cm, in, mm, etc units do not correspond to real life dimensions. There is also no way to get the specific device DPI, the nearest you get is the `window.devicePixelRatio` property. One way to solve the problem would be using external libraries like [Detector](http://detector.dmolsen.com/) to determine the exact device the user is in and then assign any hard coded Pixel density to it as listed in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density).
Once you somehow have the density you can easily convert any dimension to the desired size.
For example, on an Ipad3:

```
var dpr     = window.devicePixelRatio;
var inch    = 25.4; //1inch = 25.4 mm
var ppi     = 264; //Ipad3 density

function mmToPx(mm){
    return ((mm/inch)*ppi)/dpr;
}

myElement.width = mmToPx(size_in_mm);
```

I hope it helps anybody with the same problem…

Answer (score 2):

This statement on MDN reads as it should work on devices with a high resolution:

> For low-dpi devices, the unit px represents the physical reference pixel and the others are defined relative to it. Thus, 1in is defined as 96px which equals 72pt. The consequence of this definition is that on such devices, length described in inches (in), centimeters (cm), millimeters (mm) doesn't necessary match the length of the physical unit with the same name.
>
> For high-dpi devices, inches (in), centimeters (cm), millimeters (mm) are defined as their physical counterparts. Therefore the px unit is defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

And then there is also `mozmm` – » An experimental unit which attempts to render at exactly one millimeter regardless of the size or resolution of the display.« (See the link above.)

Comment: I just realized `1px` doesn't mean `one pixel` in high-dpi devices :O

Comment: So these units just wont work. I can't believe its impossible to display something with its real dimensions…

Comment: @Drala it's understandable, it depends on the capability of the screen device, you can image that if that screen has the resolution of only 10x10 and its physical size is about 10cm x 10cm, that means one pixel on that screen equals 1cm, so how could you display something smaller 1cm? with high resolution screen, you can approximately display everything (due to the limited capability of human eyes).

Comment: @King King but at least we should be able to retrieve the resolution. If i´m on an ipad3 I should be able to read 264 px/in

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - probably because if it had, many many websites would be unusable on high-res devices.