# How do I measure how many element fit in a specific paper size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where I have to display a list of people but the UI should look like its a print preview. Making it look like a paper is easy enough using a div and some CSS but the problem I am having is knowing how many divs I need. I don't know how to determine how much of the content fits 1 paper (div).

I can't assume just a number because the user can change the div size (like its height) and also even the scaling. Can anyone lead me to where I should start looking please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How emulate real size dimensions in css/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166686/how-emulate-real-size-dimensions-in-css-javascript)

Comment: or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497481/how-to-get-correct-rendering-size-when-printing-html-elements